# Ruled the kingdom of Dahomey vs Ruled the battle of Dahomey

Tags: sentence-construction

> Behanzin ruled the West African
> **kingdom/battle**
> of Dahomey at the end of the nineteenth century, a time when Europeans were doing their utmost to colonize Africa. Behanzin put up extremely powerful resistance. He did this with the
> aid
> of an army, including five thousand female warriors. He is often called King Shark, a name suggesting strength and wisdom. Famed for being a
> poet
> as well as a warrior, he wrote some of the most beautiful songs ever produced in Dahomey.

**My Approach**

As per definition,

Kingdom --> a country/state rules by a king or queen

battle --> fight

I am confused by seeing the definition of the correct word based on context.

Can anyone guide me to the correct answer?
Thanks in advance

Comment: It has to be "kingdom", because songs are not usually produced in a battle! If it was the "battle of Dahomy", I doubt there would be any writing of music going on during the fighting. But the "kingdom of Dahomy" could very well produce music. Plus, while to say he "ruled" a battle could technically be correct, meaning "he won it easily and spectacularly", it would be an awfully slangy way to put it!

Comment: What do you think is the correct answer, and why.  Your prior research seems to make this very clear "Kingdom --> a country/state rules by a king or queen"  "battle --> fight"  Only one of these can be "ruled" as per these definitions.